# Google Admin: Cannot Redirect Primary Domain

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm currently hosting a website using GCP, and want to redirect my naked domain (worldslastgarden.com) to www.worldslastgarden.com through Google Admin.

When I go to set up the redirect, it's automatically set to "http://app-id=annular-system-265404,domain=gmail.worldslastgarden.com", which I assume has been automatically set by GCP (as my project is annular-system-265404). Upon changing the redirect to a www subdomain, the page spews a "G Suite - Server error We are unable to process your request at this time, please try again later."

I'm assuming I've done something wrong but not exactly sure where at all.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please see [sf] for networking and infrastructure related questions.

Comment: Could you confirm where do you have hosted your website in GCP? It is on Google App Engine or any other product?